# C# - Get all environment variables in sorted order

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

I'm trying to get a sorted list of all environment variables for logging purpose using System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() which returns an IDictionary.

According to the documentation IDictionary does not provide any functionality for sorting:
[IDictionary Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-6.0#remarks)

> The IDictionary interface allows the contained keys and values to be enumerated, but it does not imply any particular sort order.

As kind of workaround i came up with something like this:

```
var dictionary = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();

var keyList = dictionary.Keys.OfType<string>().ToList();
keyList.Sort();

int maxKeyLen = keyList.Max(key => ((string)key).Length);

string logMessage = "";

foreach (string key in keyList)
{
    logMessage = 
        logMessage + 
        Environment.NewLine + 
        (key + ": ").PadRight(maxKeyLen + 2) + 
        dictionary[key];
}

Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
```

#### Update

Due to the solution of [@canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71616756/18578004) I changed the upper code to this:

```
var sortedEntries = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(entry => entry.Key);

int maxKeyLen = sortedEntries.Max(entry => ((string)entry.Key).Length);

string logMessage = "";

foreach (var entry in sortedEntries)
{
    logMessage =
        logMessage +
        Environment.NewLine +
        (entry.Key + ": ").PadRight(maxKeyLen + 2) +
        entry.Value;
}

Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
```

Comment: With this i receive error CS1061 'IDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'IDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

GetEnvironmentVariables returns an IDictionary, not an IDictionary<TKey,TValue>

Comment: `var sortedKeysAndValues = dictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(x => (string)x.Key)`?

Comment: It's funny that `dictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` and `dictionary.Keys.OfType<string>()` are essentially identical techniques..

Comment: Environment variables often contain secrets so keep that in mind as you log them.

Comment: @CaiusJard "*It's funny that `dictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` and `dictionary.Keys.OfType<string>()` are essentially identical techniques..*" - well, except that the former avoids needing to do a lookup for every key

Comment: @Crowcoder yes sure, it's not for external use. But thank you for the hint

Comment: I meant "techniques for resolving the 'ancient collection implements IE but not IE<T>' problem"..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` returns a non-generic `IDictionary`. `IDictionary` implements `IEnumerable`, and even though this isn't clear from the interface without reading the documentation, every member you get when iterating over it is a [`DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry?view=net-6.0).

A `DictionaryEntry` is basically just a pre-generics `KeyValuePair<object, object>`.

Linq provides two methods for moving from a non-generic `IEnumerable` to a generic `IEnumerable<T>`: `Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>()`. In this case, since we know that every element is a `DictionaryEntry`, we can use `Cast<DictionaryEntry>()`.

So:

```
var entries = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Cast<DictionaryEntry>();
```

Now we've got an `IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>`. We could just sort this:

```
var sortedEntries = entries.OrderBy(x => (string)x.Key);
```

Or we could turn it into a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` first to make it easier to work with:

```
var entries = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(x => KeyValuePair.Create((string)x.Key, (string)x.Value));
var sortedEntries = entries.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't even need to be a `KVP<TK,TV>` - maybe some anonymous type would be fine?

Comment: Sure, or a tuple. I chose a `KVP<string, string>` because it might be more familiar to OP if they're used to working with generic dictionaries, but they can do whatever they want

Comment: @canton7 this solution works just fine for my purpose. Thank you very much!

Comment: var entries = Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariables().Cast<DictionaryEntry>();
change to
var entries = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Cast<DictionaryEntry>();